# Form in JSP Page not Submitting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a jsp page which has a form embedded and I'm submitting the form via JavaScript.

When the page has say aroung 10-50 items the submit is working fine but if the page has aroud 500 items or more its not submitting.

After I click the submit button the page just stays in the current page and it just keeps loading.

How can I solve this issue.

A sample code is shown below:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitChecked() {
   var approveStr="";
   var approveArr=new Array();
   if(document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer.length != undefined)
   {
      for(var i=0; i < document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer.length; i++) 
      {
         if(document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer[i].checked)
         {
            approveStr +=document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer[i].value + ",";
            approveArr.push(document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer[i].value); 
         }
      }
      if(approveStr=="")
          alert("Please make a selection by clicking atleast one checkbox");
      else 
      {

        document.getElementById("passCheckVerVal").value=approveArr;
        document.forms["newForm"].submit();
      }
   }   //end of if checking multiple checkboxes
else   //if the page has only one checkbox(version)
   {
       if(document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer.checked)
       {
           window.location = "process.jsp?passCheckVer="+document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer.value+'&u_trackingRequestID=<%=request.getParameter("u_trackingRequestID")%>';
       }
       else
         alert("Please make a selection by clicking atleast one checkbox");
   }
}
</script>
<body>
<%
String newTrackingReqId=request.getParameter("u_trackingRequestID");
%>
<form name=frmReleaseDetail>
//jdbc code
//100's checkbox named checkBoxVer
//button to invoke submitChecked javascript function
</form>
<form name=newForm" id="newForm" action="process.jsp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="passCheckVer" id="passCheckVerVal"/>
<input type="hidden" name="u_trackingRequestID" id="u_trackingRequestIDVal" value="<%=newTrackingReqId%>"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show the code, please

Comment: please include the code in your post. Use post method in the form.

Comment: @david: Please share your code. Did you get the response from the server?

Comment: Added a small snippet.If the code is not sufficient pls suggest on what part i can stress more

Comment: After a very long time I got the respose say after 25 mins after I submitted.Is ther any way to make this faster.

Comment: where is `submitChecked()` being called?

Comment: which webserver are you using?

Comment: The submitChecked() is being called in another form named frmReleaseDetail as I've shown.Since it has too much code I've just added comments as to what it contains.

Comment: @ Aashray: I'm using tomcat container.

Comment: Tomcat is meant to handle small number of requests. Try using jboss or websphere.

Comment: I cant change production container just coz this issue. Any other suggestions? The issue here is its working but 25 mins in not a realistic amount of time anyone can wait in a page.

Comment: @david.colais Can you try removing all the validations in your code and just submit the form as-is

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the form method to POST.

```
<form name=frmReleaseDetail method="post">
```

By default the method is GET. More informations [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html). You have quantity of data limitation lot smaller in GET.

**EDIT :**

Code suggestion with only one form :

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitChecked() {
   var checked = false;

   for(var i=0; i < document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer.length; i++) 
      {
         if(document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer[i].checked)
         {
            checked = true;
            break;
         }
      }

   if((document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer.length != undefined and checked) or (document.frmReleaseDetail.checkBoxVer.checked))
   {
      document.forms["frmReleaseDetail"].submit();
   }
else
   {
       alert("Please make a selection by clicking atleast one checkbox");
   }
</script>
<body>
<%
String newTrackingReqId=request.getParameter("u_trackingRequestID");
%>
<form id="frmReleaseDetail" name="frmReleaseDetail" action="process.jsp" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="u_trackingRequestID" id="u_trackingRequestIDVal" value="<%=newTrackingReqId%>"/>
//jdbc code
//100's checkbox named checkBoxVer
//button to invoke submitChecked javascript function
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not the form with the name frmReleaseDetail that I'm submitting its the form with the name "newForm" fetting submitted.This form is at the bottom of the code snippet.

Comment: Why not only use one form with everything inside it, and remove JavaScript conversion from form1 frmReleaseDetail to newForm? It will be a lot easier and your JSP will do the job.

Comment: Coz frmReleaseDetail is submitting to another jsp page that's the reason for using another form submit via java script.

Comment: Submit by JavaScript is ok, but the question is why transfer data from one to another since in both cases you are posting to process.jsp. The only thing useful in JavaScript is the checkbox validation.

Comment: Let me clarify the form named "frmReleaseDetail" is submitting to a jsp named approve.jsp and the form named "newForm" is submitting to process.jsp. I created the newForm and submitted via java script is coz I had to add an additional functionality.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone making **noob (newbie) mistakes**:

---

**1: Type is "submit" NOT "button"**

**GOOD/CORRECT:**----------------------------------------------

```
<input type="submit" value="some_button_label" />
```

**BAD/INCORRECT:**----------------------------------------------

```
<input type="button" value="some_button_label" />
```

---

**2: Submit button needs to be nested inside the form.**

**GOOD/CORRECT:**----------------------------------------------

```
<form action="cookies-personalize-response.jsp">
    SEL_YOUR_FAV_PROG_LANG
    <select name="fav_lan">
        <option>LANG_01</option>
        <option>LANG_02</option>
        <option>LANG_03</option>
    </select>
    <input
        type ="submit"
        value="some_button_label"
    />
</form>
```

**BAD/INCORRECT:**------------------------------------------------

```
<form action="cookies-personalize-response.jsp">
    SEL_YOUR_FAV_PROG_LANG
    <select name="fav_lan">
        <option>LANG_01</option>
        <option>LANG_02</option>
        <option>LANG_03</option>
        <option>LANG_04</option>
    </select>  
</form>
<input
    type ="submit"
    value="some_button_label"
/>
```

---

**3: Referesh page after fix**, view source in browser to make sure actually changed.
As silly as the last answer is, it is actually the one that I got stuck on the longest.